Integrals of Vector Valued Paths
Let $X:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be paths, and $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.
If everything is nice and differentiable, then we define the path (line) integral as
$$
\int^b_a f(Y_t)dX_t = \int^b_a f(Y_t) \dot{X}_t dt
$$
If $X$ is not differentiable, but still nice enough, we can define the Riemann-Stieltjes integral
$$
\int^b_a f(Y_t)dX_t = \lim_{|\pi_n| \rightarrow 0}\sum^{N}_{i=1} f(Y_{c_i})(X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i})
$$
where $\pi_n = \{a = t_{n_0} < t_{n_1} < \cdots < t_{n_N} = b \}$ is a mesh and $|\pi_n| = \sup\{|t_{n_{i+1}} - t_{n_i}|\}$ is the mesh size and $c_i \in [t_{i}, t_{i+1}]$.
My question is how do we define these things when the paths are multi-dimensional. For instance if $X:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ and $Y:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^e$. Also, in this case what spaces must $f$ be defined on?

A line/path integral is defined by: $f : D \to \Bbb R$ is a function on an open set $D\subseteq \Bbb R^d$ and $X : [a, b] \to D$ is a continuous map (that is, a curve). Then $$\int_X f,ds := \int_a^b f(X(t))|X'(t)|,dt$$ The "$ds$" indicates that the integration is with respect to arclength along the curve $X$ (which is why there is a multiplication by $|X'(t)|$ in the definition). Thus the value is independent of exactly how the geometric curve (the image of $X$) is parametrized. There is no second curve $Y$ involved. Also be aware that "Path Integral" has a 2nd meaning in Quantum Mech.

You also have line integrals of vector-valued maps $F: D\to \Bbb R^d$ defined by $$\int_X F\cdot dX := \int_a^b F(X(t))\cdot X'(t),dt$$ where "$\cdot$" is the inner product. This still leaves the integration on the right as being of a real-valued function on the interval $[a.b]$, and independent of the parametrization, provided it is in the same direction.

@PaulSinclair Thanks for the reply! I understand what you are saying w.r.t integrals of the form a) $\int f(X_t)dX_t$ when $X$ is smooth (so that we can write $dX_t = \dot{X}_tdt$) and $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and b) $\int F(X_t) \cdot dX_t$ which is read as $\int F(X_t) \cdot \dot{X}_tdt$. But both of these rely on $X$ being smooth. How do we define these when $X$ is not smooth? Also how do we handle the case with two "curves" - you say that there is no second curve $Y$ involved but my motivation for this question comes from an example when there is a $Y$ involved?

@PaulSinclair I am trying to understand the Controlled ODE of the form $dY_t = V(Y_t) dX_t$ which in integral form is $Y_t = y + \int^t_a V(Y_s) dX_s$. The terms are defined as follows; $X:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$, $Y:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^e$, and $V: \mathbb{R}^e \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^e)$. Ideally I want to understand this when $X$ is not smooth. But I don't even get this when $X$ is smooth, ie when we can do $dX_t = \dot{X}_t dt$.

You talked about line integrals, but gave something that didn't match up, so I was just pointing out what a line integral actually is. By worrying about line integrals, you are wasting your time. The integral you are working in is just a normal 1-dim integration of a map into a higher-dimensional space. If you are not sure about the latter, you can view it coordinate-wise, where it is just $e$ integrations of functions $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$. Or so I assume, but I don't know what you mean by $(\Bbb R^d, \Bbb R^e)$, Is that $\Bbb R^d\times \Bbb R^e$, or is it some space of functions, or what?

And I don't now what "multiplication" there is between $V(Y_s)$ and $dX_s$, i.e., between elements of $(\Bbb R^d, \Bbb R^e)$ and $\Bbb R^d$.

@PaulSinclair Sorry thats a typo. It should say $L(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}^e)$ which is the space of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^d$ into $\mathbb{R}^e$. These can all be represented by $e \times d$ matrices.

Okay. That makes sense then. For the smooth case $$\int^t_a V(Y_s) dX_s = \int^t_a V(Y_s)(X's),ds$$, which translates to a Stieltjes integral as $$\lim{|\pi_n| \to 0}\sum^{N}{i=1} V(Y{c_i})(X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i})$$ For each $s$, $V(Y_s)$ is a linear map from $\Bbb R^d \to \Bbb R^e$, and thus $V(Y_s)(X'_s) \in \Bbb R^e$, The result is a map $\widehat V: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^e$ with coordinates $(\widehat V_1,\dots,\widehat V_e)$, and $$\int^t_a V(Y_s) dX_s = \left(\int^t_a \widehat V_1(s),ds, \dots,\int^t_a \widehat V_e(s),ds\right)$$each of which is just an ordinary 1D integral.

@PaulSinclair That makes sense thank you! I also came up with the following interpretation. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong as its different to yours? s

@PaulSinclair That makes sense thank you! I also came up with the following interpretation. Could you please tell me where I'm going wrong as its different to yours? $V = (V_1, \cdots, V_d)$ where $V_i : \mathbb{R}^e \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^e$. Thus, $V(Y_s) = (V_1(Y_s), \cdots, V_d(Y_s))$. Now, $V_j(Y_s) = (V_j(Y_s)^1, \cdots, V_j(Y_s)^e)^T \in \mathbb{R}^e$. Thus  $V(Y_s)$ is a $e \times d$- matrix that looks like $ \begin{bmatrix}
V_1(Y_s)^1 & \cdots & V_d(Y_s)^1 \
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \
V_1(Y_s)^e & \cdots & V_d(Y_s)^e
\end{bmatrix}  $

Then, $V(Y_s)\dot{X}s = (V_1(Y_s)^1 \dot{X}^1_s + \cdots + V_d(Y_s)^1 \dot{X}^d_s, \cdots, V_1(Y_s)^e \dot{X}^1_s + \cdots + V_d(Y_s)^e \dot{X}^d_s)^T \in \mathbb{R}^e$. Hence we get that $Y^j_t = y^j + \sum^d{i=1} \int^t_a V_i(Y_s)^j \dot{X}^i_s ds$.

Why do you think yours is different from mine? I left it at a high level approach that gives the basics, whereas you chose to interpret the linear maps in terms of matrices (absolutely required if one is going to do actual calculations, but otherwise, the added details obfuscate the ideas instead of clarifying them, IMO). But in the end, it is the same thing. Your $\sum_{i=1}^d V_i(Y_s)^j\dot X_s^i$ is my $\widehat V_j(s)$.
